# Why don't we get a shock touching neutral wire?

Tags: electricity, electric-circuits, electric-current, electrical-resistance, voltage

Neutral wire has a V same as ground i.e almost 0. Also it carries some current. So if we touch the wire don't we to become a part of the circuit? Even if we are on the ground and current should flow through us, but I read we don't get a shock as there is no potential difference between ground and neutral wire, but the current was already flowing from live wire (220 V) to 0, so shouldn't we get a shock?

Comment: Current only flows when there is a potential difference.

Comment: The question contains the term “potential difference”. It’s good that you are aware of this term. The key word for this comment is “difference”. The difference between the live and neutral/ground wires is 220 V (or whatever it is for your electricity network), and that is all that matters. Usually we just define the neutral/ground wires to have a potential of *exactly* zero (assuming neutral and ground are at the same potential); then the live wire’s potential equals the potential difference between live and neutral/ground.

Comment: If you touch the neutral wire in a live circuit, whether it be a lamp, an appliance or something else, it is the same as touching the active wire. It is only "safe" to touch the neutral wire when there is no current flowing, just as it is "safe" to touch the earth wire (when one exists). That is, "safe" is relative.

Comment: I have had a shock from a neutral wire!

Comment: @AryanBeezadhur nope, I was there, it was not static. It was caused by some "work in progress" wiring. As several people have pointed out it is easy for the neutral to become hot due to a fault condition. Line and neutral reversed by installation error is also more common than you might think. And I have seen plenty of inverters which actually have a split phase output, so the neutral isn't 0V relative to earth, and it will light up a neon screwdriver.

Comment: @Rodney I thought you were talking about a lone neutral wire lying around! xD

Comment: @Mick That's wrong. Touching the neutral wire is much, much safer than touching the live, though it's still hardly recommended. **Assuming there are no faults on the supply side,** the potential difference between neutral and the ground should not be more than a couple stray volts, which is not even enough to feel. If there *is* a neutral fault on the supply side, the neutral voltage could potentially rise all the way to 230V (depending on phase balancing) and kill you. The live voltage is always *guaranteed* to be at 230V with respect to ground though, which is definitely worse.

Comment: @Demonblack in a live circuit there is electricity in both the active and neutral wires. Only when there is no circuit is there no current flow. Yes, on the live side of a light/power switch, when in the "off" position, will the live wire have 110/240V and the neutral have about 0V, but in the "on" position both wires will have 240V relative to earth.

Comment: and that is without considering the powerpoints I have seen where a qualified/licenced electrician has connected the mains to the neutral side, or the earth wire has also been live. Thankfully that last is not so common with RCDs becoming more widespread. Without RCDs, with a 3-pin plug one could almost* get away with connecting the wires in random order.

Comment: @Mick "in the "on" position both wires will have 240V relative to earth." No, like I said before that is completely wrong. The fact that there is current _flowing_ through the neutral doesn't mean that the neutral has potential referenced to ground, because the voltage drop happens entirely across the load; it's basic electronics. The neutral side will have 0V relative to earth **unless there is a fault** with the neutral conductor. In a monophase circuit if there is a neutral fault the neutral on the load side will immediately rise to 230V, but in a circuit that's operating correctly it's 0V.

Comment: To clarify: what that means is that if you disconnect the "neutral" of your load from the "neutral" in the wall, the "neutral" of the load effectively becomes live, and of course if you touch it you'll get a shock. But if the neutral is correctly connected (all the way from the load to the generator, so there must be no faults on the supplier's neutral conductor either, which is the normal condition) then the voltage between neutral and ground is ~0. You can easily measure this with a $5 multimeter. You'll read 230V between live and neutral, 230V across live-earth, and 0V across neutral-earth.

Comment: It's hard to explain this in detail in the comments, but basically the neutral coming from the supplier is a ground referenced sink which will absorb any amount of current you throw at it without ever rising above 0V. As soon as you connect the neutral to another point in the circuit, the neutral pulls that point down to 0V, absorbing as much current as is necessary to do so. The extreme case is if you directly connect it to the live (short circuit): it will try to pull the live down to 0V, absorbing immense amounts of current to try and do so and destroying the circuit.

Comment: Of course if your installation is wired in reverse that is a problem, but that just falls under the general rule of "never trust the wire colors if you haven't put them in yourself". (By the way RCDs don't care if you reverse live and neutral, and they don't directly sense the earth)

Comment: Yes, the voltage is dropped across the load. That one side will have 0V relative to earth is **only** true for a **DC system**. With AC for one half of the cycle the current is flowing in one direction and flowing in the other direction for the other half of the cycle. Without this RCDs would not work since they cut out when the current is unbalanced between the supply and return conductors. If the neutral is pulled to ground then the RCD will disconnect the circuit; neutral at ground potential indicates a fault condition.

Comment: @Mick Look, I'm sorry but you are just factually wrong. Neutral is tied to the ground at the generator. You keep mixing up neutral-live and neutral-ground references. It doesn't matter if the neutral is at +230V with respect to live when the sine wave inverts. It could be at +500kV for all I care, the point is that **both** neutral **and** ground would be at 500kV, because _neutral is referenced to ground_ and thus by definition there cannot be a potential difference between neutral and ground, unless there is a fault. No potential difference, no current.

Comment: I'll just add that three phase railways often used this fact, they had no neutral at all because they were running perfectly balanced loads all the time, so they just had two aerial phases with the third phase being in the rails. In this case, instead of neutral, _the third phase_ was referenced to ground. The fact people weren't getting fried left and right by the exposed rails and absolutely zero precautions needed to be taken is proof enough of my explanation.

Comment: As far as RCDs go, they do measure current flowing from the phase back to the neutral, you are correct; but like I said before current flow in a conductor does not imply a potential difference between said conductor and the ground, just like in the case of the three phase railway. I'm sorry if I come across as condescending but I keep coming up to the character limit and having to cut out parts even when writing multiple comments...

Comment: \*facepalm\* Yes, you're right. I'm an idiot. Or not enough sleep, take your pick. :-p It *should* be "safe" to touch the neutral wire but I wouldn't stake my life on it.

Answer (score 44):

**Do not touch even the neutral wire in a live circuit!** There are numerous failure modes that could make you dead wrong about not getting shocked.

The neutral wire does have current going through it. However, we do not get shocked when we touch something with current going through it, we get shocked when current goes through us. In this case all of the current that enters one end of the section of wire we are touching also leaves the other end. None goes through us so we don’t get shocked.

Why does no current go through us? From the perspective of a circuit we are, to a first approximation, just a big human shaped resistor. The current through a resistor is proportional to the voltage across it. Since the neutral is at the same voltage as the ground, both our head and our feet are at 0 V. So the voltage across us is 0 V and therefore the current is 0 A.

Comment: Mandatory ElectroBOOM link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XDf2nhfxVzg

Comment: You should never touch plugged in wires or outlets period without testing. Always test regardless of what you think is "turned off". Outlets are more than capable of killing you (it can kill about 100 of you in parallel if setup right).

Comment: Even without failure modes, the voltage at the neutral terminal of an outlet could be significantly different from 0V due to the voltage "drop" in the neutral wire. It shouldn't be enough for you to feel it (and I reiterate what others have said DON'T TOUCH IT) but in most cases it will be enough that a neutral-earth short will trip a GFCI / RCD type breaker.

Comment: I feel this is missing something. Say you touch the neutral wire half way along then the current at that point has not yet reached ground and will continue flowing. So why does it choose to flow through the wire and not the person touching the wire? This feels like what the question is asking and doesn't seem to have been covered here explicitly. I assume its because the bug human shaped resistor has a massively higher resistance than the remaining part of the wire and that there is in fact a very very small potential difference, but these two factors just mean that the current is undetectable

Comment: @Nelson I'm curious about that setup...

Comment: @Chris that was covered explicitly. It is the whole last paragraph

Comment: @Dale: I'm not sure it is but maybe I just explained myself wrong (or am making some bad assumption somewhere). If I am reading you correctly you are saying that the point on the neutral wire I am touching is at zero. That my feet are at zero and that ground is zero. By extension of that logic it feels like I can conclude that the current also doesn't flow in the wire from the point I am touching the wire to its neutral terminal since the potential difference there is zero too. This is clearly wrong though because we know the current is flowing in the wire.

Comment: @Chris to a first approximation the wire is an ideal conductor. It does not require a voltage difference to carry a current. Do not universally associate current with voltage difference. It is only true in the specific case of a resistor which is why it is important to state that the human behaves as a resistor

Comment: @Dale: Aha. Thanks for the clarification. It makes more sense now!

Comment: "In this case all of the current that enters one end of the section of wire we are touching also leaves the other end": impossible real case. "Why does no current go through us? ": always some current goes through us. All these statements assumes an ideal conductor, very far from the usual scenarios.

Comment: @Dale I didn't quite get your point about current not always require voltage difference to flow since I was always taught that current is dependent on voltage difference for its flow.please clarify.thanks

Comment: @sneh versha unfortunately that is an incorrect impression that many instructors accidentally leave in their students minds. It only applies to resistors. Capacitors can have voltage with no current. Inductors can have current with no voltage. Superconductors (or “ideal” conductors) can have current with no voltage. Inductors and capacitors can both have negative voltage with positive current or positive voltage with negative current. Transistors and transformers have even more complicated relationships between voltage and current. The bottom line is that not everything behaves as a resistor

Comment: @Dale Alright!thanks for clarification.i didn't know about this

Answer (score 21):

#### Why don't we?  Actually we could!

Your first line is the assumption which will kill you.  Literally.

> Neutral wire has a V same as ground i.e almost 0.

In a perfect world, with perfect zero-impedance electrical conductors everywhere, there is no voltage between neutral and ground.  In that perfect world, you could safely touch the neutral wire.

Surprise - we don't live in a perfect world...

Electricity transmission doesn't actually have a neutral.  Instead it has 3 wires which all have AC on them, where the AC waves on each are out of step with the others.  When the electricity gets to your local substation near your house, it goes through a transformer to step down the voltage, and also to kind of "add" the three AC signals.  Because the AC voltage waves are out of step with each other, adding them together like this gives a "zero" voltage in the middle, which is the neutral.

To keep the neutral close to ground, it's wired to ground (a physical metal rod into the earth!) through some resistance.  It can't be tied to ground too well though, because lightning strikes nearby would go back up the neutral and be incredibly dangerous.  (They still can, by the way, but the damage is mostly fairly low because of this.)

Separately, your house also has a physical metal rod into the earth which is connected to the ground points of all your outlets.

So how can this go wrong...?

Well, "ground" here isn't "ground" elsewhere.  That's why your house has its own metal rod into the earth. Various things (lightning, chemical reactions in the soil, friction of air over the ground, air humidity, just for examples) make for voltage differences between places.  Famously, that's why cows can be killed by a nearby lightning strike - there is enough voltage between each foot, across the ground they're standing on, to electrocute them.  So even if the neutral was at "ground" at the transformer, it might not be by the time it reaches your house.

Or connections can get broken.  If your house earth becomes corroded or breaks, or the same thing happens at the transformer, all bets are off on whether you're at ground or not.

Or you can get a short-circuit from live to neutral. In theory this should trip a breaker.  But suppose you don't have a breaker, or someone has replaced a fuse with a nail in an old house.  The resistances along live and back along neutral will be roughly equal, so the neutral wire at your outlet will be around half the live voltage.  (And then the wire insulation tends to burn and set the house on fire, but that's a separate problem.)

Or you can get a fault in electricity transmission where one phase connection is broken.  Instead of the three phases adding together to cancel out and produce the neutral, now you've got a damn great AC voltage on the neutral.  Usually there is protection against this getting out, so all power should be shut off if this happens, but in a rural setting with older kit (or on somewhere like a farm where it's managed by the farmer) I would not bet my life on it.

Or more ironically, something somewhere else might have a fault where it's shorted live to earth.  You might be safe to touch neutral (apart from the issues above), but if you held onto earth in one hand and neutral in the other, it'd be the earth which kills you.

Just a few examples there. I'm not pretending this is an exhaustive list of the ways you can kill yourself with the neutral - I'm just trying to give you a flavour of why this is a bad idea, and why your incorrect assumption proves fatal to so many people every year. Don't add to those statistics.

Comment: Well.. at least here there was the concept of 'classical grounding' so the outlets were supplied by two wires and in the outlet neutral was connected to ground to provide ground. Usually metal housings of devices are connected to the ground pin, so a lot of people were touchen the neutral wire when touching any electrical appliance with a metal casing. Havent heard of people getting shocked (but maybe havent heard enough). But I agree: dont do it intentionally

Comment: @lalala They most certainly have been shocked, and people have died. That's why new standards require double insulation instead of simply grounding the chassis. If everything is setup correctly, then it is safe, but if something isn't wired correctly, then it is possible for the neutral (and even ground!) to carry current and hurt/kill someone.

Answer (score 7):

> if we touch the wire don't we to become a part of the circuit?

"Circuit" comes from the same Latin word as "circle," or "circus." A circuit is a *loop*. The only way you can ever have a steady flow of electric current is if it flows around a loop. If you touch a wire, but you are insulated from everything else, then you aren't part of any loop, and there can be no steady flow through your body.  But...

---

...It gets a little more complicated when we're talking about Alternating Current (AC), because then we can talk about current "flowing through" a [*capacitor*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capacitor) even despite the fact that the two terminals of the capacitor are electrically insulated from each other.

Any time some electrically conductive thing comes near some other electrically conductive thing, there is weak capacitance between them. Notably, there always is weak capacitance between yourself and Earth.

Even if you are well insulated from everything else, you still will feel a strong "tingle" if you touch the "hot" wire in a circuit because a tiny amount of AC current is able to flow in a loop from the generating station, through the hot wire, through your body, through the capacitance between your body and Earth, and through the Earth back to the Earth wire at the generating station.

You aren't *supposed* to feel any tingle* if you touch the neutral wire, because the neutral wire should be connected to Earth someplace not too far from where you are standing. Effectively, both ends of the "capacitor" are connected to the same thing (Earth), and so it's not really part of any loop or circuit.

---

* But note what other answers already have told you.  What is *supposed* to be is not always the same as what actually *is*. Touching the neutral still is risky because a fault in the wiring could cause a supposed-to-be-neutral wire to actually be "hot."

Don't go around touching live circuits.

Answer (score 5):

Neutral is near to 0 v, lets say 15v in a domestic installation. As all wires has some low resistance (lets say 5 ohm as example), we can model this system as a point of low voltage (15v) with a low resistor (5 ohm) connected from it to real ground (0v).

When someone (don't do that at home) touches the neutral wire, the change in the circuit is that appears a new connection path from the touch point, across the body, to the ground. The body has an (usual) impedance bigger to 1000 ohm (it depends of person, fingers pressure, conditions, shoes, ...).

Now, the circuit is a parallel of connection of two "resistors" from neutral touch point to ground: the wire (5 ohms) and the body (1000 ohms). By circuits law, the amount of current that will go across the body will be 5/(1000+5)=0.5% of the total current. Usually, that means a level of current that can not cause big injuries.

However, these values are too near to dangerous current intensities and, in some scenarios, a really dangerous current can go across the body.

Don't do that at home.

(a comment about biology: if you must touch a wire -don't do it-, touch it with the reverse of the fingers. In case of shock, muscles tends to close the fingers, so, the fingers will jump out of the cable contact. Instead, if you touch with the internal side of the fingers, you risk that shock closes the fingers around the cable, making it a deadly and insurmountable closure).